# issue with obtaining "Default Store View" value for custom attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using the below code to get attribute name

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','pricee');
echo $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);

$attribute->getFrontendLabel()
```

in this 'pricee' is the attribute code. But the output is not the desired one, instead the value under "Admin" is retrieved. Below screen shows the actual field i need to show

[image]

What am i doing wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: Hmm, try add `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(<needed_store_id>);` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the below code worked in my case,

```
 
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();

echo $attribute->getStoreLabels();
```

The output of this is : `Array
(
    [1] => Price
)`

Answer (score 2):

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');

This will select the default store that you are after.

You can also try the getStoreLabel($storeId) function for more specific stuff.

This function is found at: /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Return store label of attribute
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStoreLabel($storeId = null)
{
    if ($this->hasData('store_label')) {
        return $this->getData('store_label');
    }
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    $label = false;
    if (!$store->isAdmin()) {
        $labels = $this->getStoreLabels();
        if (isset($labels[$store->getId()])) {
            return $labels[$store->getId()];
        }
    }
    return $this->getFrontendLabel();
}
```

HTH,

Shaun O'Reilly